# Schedule notification android

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I've seen a simple app to schedule a notification 5 seconds after a button is pressed. But what I really want to do is to schedule a notification to a specific time (e.g. the notification is shown at 00:00) but I don't really know how to set that moment in time (because now I'm using a "delay").
Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_5:
            scheduleNotification(getNotification("5 second delay"), 5000);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int delay) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
}

private Notification getNotification(String content) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Scheduled Notification");
    builder.setContentText(content);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    return builder.build();
}

}
```

And the NotificationPublisher class

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

}
}
```

It would be even better if I knew how to schedule the notification in order that a notification appears everyday at 00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code for the same:

```
public static void setNotificationScheduler(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationPublisher.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 999999, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    // Set the alarm to start at 00:00
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for O+ devices which apps have not run https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this problem before. So I'd be glad to help you out so you don't waste much time as I did I'll try to be as simple and concise as possible.

- Get the Alarm service from the system.
- Make a pending intent, passing in the broadcast receiver class's
  name.
- Make a calendar object and set the time of it too 8 am.
- Check if the current time is past 8. If yes then add another day to
  it.
- Call the set repeating method of AlarmManager class.

Sample code for the same:

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmIntent = new Intent(context of current file, AlarmReceiver1.class); // AlarmReceiver1 = broadcast receiver

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  Menu.this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmIntent.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"+System.currentTimeMillis())));
alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
if (now.after(alarmStartTime)) {
       Log.d("Hey","Added a day");
       alarmStartTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
Log.d("Alarm","Alarms set for everyday 8 am.");
```

Coming to the broadcast receiver class. You need to register your broadcast receiver in the manifest. This will cause you to receive clock events.

Override the onReceive method of this broadcast receiver and make a notification there itself or make a seperate notification building service and build and display your notification there.

The manifest code snippet:

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver1"  android:enabled="true">
```

The broadcast receiver code snippet:

```
    public class AlarmReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Intent service1 = new Intent(context, NotificationService1.class);
      service1.setData((Uri.parse("custom://"+System.currentTimeMillis())));
                  context.startService(service1);
    }
```

Notification building service code snippet:

```
    public class NotificationService1 extends IntentService{

        private NotificationManager notificationManager;
        private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        private static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        Notification notification;
    @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
               notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, Activity to be opened after clicking on the notif);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("test", "test");
                mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);    

                Resources res = this.getResources();
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
                notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                            .setTicker("ticker value")
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setPriority(8)
                            .setSound(soundUri)
                            .setContentTitle("Notif title")
                            .setContentText("Text").build();
                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                notification.ledARGB = 0xFFFFA500;
                notification.ledOnMS = 800;
                notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
                notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
                Log.i("notif","Notifications sent.");

        }

    }
```

For Help regarding to code then it is available here: http://www.singhajit.com/schedule-local-notification-in-android/
There you go. That's it.
Hope this helps.

Comment: It is necessary to also add service to manifest file (with changed class name):         
<service
       android:name="com.changethis.NotificationService1"
       android:exported="false" >
</service>

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `RTC_WAKEUP`.

Instead of using a delay you could do the following:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());  
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); // For 00:00

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

You can find more information here: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html